# How do you use a piezo-electric sensor or accelerator to measure sound?

Tags: audio-recording

In my application, I need to analyze and differentiate the sound of two objects. One objects makes a high frequency pitch at 5khz which I'd like to detect. The other object tend to make sound around the 1khz range.

Rather than using a regular microphone, which is subject to ambient noise, I'm interested in piezo sensors or accelerometers that can contact the object directly.

In order to capture the high frequency pitch, does the sampling rate of the piezo sensor needs to be 10khz or above must like a regular microphone?

Also, does the contact (clamping) pressure between the sensor and the object matter?

Thanks

Comment: this probably belongs on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What are you using to capture the data?  If it is an ADC it will need to sample faster than 10khz, regardless of which sensor you use.

Answer (score 1):

Piezo sensors do not have sampling rates. Pressure on a piezo-electric device will induce a voltage across that device that can be detected and converted into an analogue audio waveform.

Your question indicates confusion between digital audio sampling theory, nyquist frequencies and analogue frequency response. Piezo-electric devices are analogue devices and are therefore not subject to Nyquist constraints.